# Perl replace string in file

Tags: file, perl, replace

I am trying to prompt user to type input and replace certain attribute in a file with the input. This is not working. abc.txt contain line "NA" and I wish to replace with "user_input". Any help? Thanks

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "<process>NA</process>";
print "Please specify process used\n";
my $process = <STDIN>;
chomp $process;

open(XML, "<", "abc.txt") or die "Couldn't open file, $!";
while(<XML>){

    s/<process>NA</process>/<process>$process</process>/g;  
}
```

Comment: You should escape symols like '/' in your regexp. Or use s#source#destination#g format

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion toolic. I found XML::LibXML module is better. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

@Blurman, if you are using some sort of /bin/sh you use the inplace option of perl with this  the one-liner :

```
echo -n 'process ? ';read p; perl -pi -e "s,<process>[^<]*</process>,<process>$p</process>,g" abc.txt
```

oh BTW, I changed `NA` w/ `[^<]*` to allow multiple consecutive runs ;)

+Michel

Answer (score 1):

The main part of your code is here:

```
open(XML, "<", "abc.txt") or die "Couldn't open file, $!";
while(<XML>){
  s/<process>NA</process>/<process>$process</process>/g;  
}
```

There are two main problems here that will stop your code doing what you want.

- You have `/` characters in side the match pattern and replacement string of your substitution operator. This means your code won't even compile. If you have `/` characters in your data, then the best option is to use a different character as the delimiter for the substitution operator.

  ```
  s|<process>NA</process>|<process>$process</process>|g;
  ```
- You change your data (which is stored in `$_`) but then you do nothing with the changed version. You need to write the changed version of the data back to a file.